# Using $emit to communicate between 2 vue instances

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to communicate between 2 Vue instances on my page using $emit and so far haven't gotten it to work.

My "main" instance has the following code

```
 <svg v-on:click="$emit('toggle_dm')" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 250 250" x="0px" y="0px"><title>Android System</title><path d="M112.39,34.73a4.22,4.22,0,0,0-1.08.14,92.18,92.18,0,0,0,23.47,181.28h.35a91.87,91.87,0,0,0,71.32-34.22h0a3.95,3.95,0,0,0-4.33-6.23A82.47,82.47,0,0,1,176,179.9h0c-44.73,0-81.78-36.39-82.59-81.1a82.31,82.31,0,0,1,21.76-57.42,4,4,0,0,0-2.79-6.65Z"></path></svg>
```

And then this communicates with the following instance that will toggle dark mode off and on.

```
var darkmode = new Vue({    
                data: {
                    darkActive: false,
                },
                methods: {
                    toggle_light_scheme: function(e) {
                        if(this.darkActive == false){
                            this.darkActive = true;
                            document.body.classList.add("dark");
                            localStorage.setItem('dark', true);

                            // Update styles
                            app.chart.data.datasets[0].fill = null;

                        }else {
                            this.darkActive = false;
                            document.body.classList.remove("dark");
                            localStorage.removeItem('dark');

                            // Update styles
                            app.chart.data.datasets[0].fill = true;

                        }

                        app.chart.update();

                    }
                },
                created() {
                    if(localStorage.getItem('dark')) {
                        this.darkActive = true;
                        document.body.classList.add("dark");
                    }else {
                        this.darkActive = false;
                    }

                },
                mounted(){
                    this.$on("toggle_dm", ()=> alert("message received"));
                }
            })
```

On clicking I don't seem to get any feedback and $on is not called at all. I have tried using `v-on:click="this.$emit('toggle_dm')"` but that only seems to throw errors.

Answer (score 0):

See if [this](https://codepen.io/vanechka222/pen/dyROged) helps

```
// template

  <div :class="['container', {'dark': darkActive}]">
    <h1>{{'Dark theme: ' + (darkActive ? 'on' : 'off')}}</h1>
    <button @click="toggleLightScheme">Toggle</button>
  </div>

// script

  data() {
    return {
      darkActive: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    toggleLightScheme() {
      this.darkActive = !this.darkActive;
    }
  },
```